# NavigationLink in SwiftUI not worked as expected

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make navigation link, here I'm creating `NavigationLink` with `isActive` based on `State` variable `isLoggedIn`. But without setting `isLoggedIn` `true` getting navigating to next screen.

- also, it's navigating on **tap** of `Email Textfield` which is **wrong**.

My **expectation** is it should navigate only after `isLoggedIn` setting to `true`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isLoggedIn = false
    @State private var email = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isLoggedIn) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .border(.gray, width: 1)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Button("Send") {
                        isLoggedIn = true
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a NavigationLink with EmptyView for label, and vstack with text and button.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation is wrong, `NavigationLink` handles user input independently (but also, additionally, can be activated programmatically).

In this scenario, to leave only programmatic activation, we need to hide navigation link, like

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        TextField("Email", text: $email)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .border(.gray, width: 1)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        Button("Send") {
            isLoggedIn = true
        }
        .background(NavigationLink(destination: // << here !!
            Text("Second View"), isActive: $isLoggedIn) { EmptyView() })

    }
    .padding()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it's working fine with this

```swift
struct MoviesListView: View {
    @State var navigate = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hi"), isActive: $navigate) {
                    Button("Add") {
                        navigate.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```